# Insight into Abel's impossibility theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Let 's consider the polynomial of degree $7$:$$f(x)=x^7-28x^6+ 322x^5-1960x^4+6769x^3-13132x^2+13068x-5040 $$ I am trying to get some insights into Abel's impossibility  theorem.

Does this theorem imply that this polynomial has no roots or it does not provide enough information to get solved using the conventional operations of arithmetic? Please, be considerate as i am fully aware that this may be so obvious for most of you. Thanks. By the way, I know that the roots of this polynomial are: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$.

Comment: Polynomials have roots, equations have solutions.

Comment: This polynomial can be written as a product of smaller polynomials, so Abel's theorem does not apply. It does apply to for instance $x^5 -x+1$, which has a root close to $-1.1673$ which cannot be written with roots and arithmetic operations in any finite way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know the roots of $f$ (I haven't checked completely, but it looks right), no (correct) theorem can imply that there are no roots, so that is obviously not what the theorem says.

What Abel's theorem says is that some polynomials of degree $5$ or higher have solutions than can't be written with any number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and root extractions (which I guess corresponds to what you called "the conventional operations of arithmetic"). It's not a matter of it not providng enough information, it's a matter of simply not being possible.

Comment: As an added clarification, Abel's theorem says this about a -general- polynomial of degree 5 or higher. There are examples of such polynomials that may be solved with "the conventional operations of arithmetic."